# Why is my code not running on elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-500

I am trying to migrate my php application to an ElasticBeansTalk environment, I created the environment and uploaded my application when I opened the link it was displayed without any problem, but when I try to log in I get error 500, I have tried to find where the error may be, but It only shows me the title, it does not specify more, if someone has any idea I leave the link:

http://prohotel-env.eba-fb9mddwm.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

they can use false credentials it will get the same error, what you would have to do is return to the same page

in local I have no problem

Comment: Did you check any logs from EB?

Answer (score 0):

500 is an internal server error, meaning something is wrong with either your code or server configuration.

Since the question and issue are, IMHO too broad to answer correctly. I would recommend looking at what your Elastic Beanstalk logs say is wrong. Those can be accessed in several ways, but if you're comfortable with using the command line you can use `eb logs --zip` to generate a `.zip` file of them.

Source: [eb logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html) command.